# PHP zip file downloading always stop at 19.8 MB size

Tags: php

I have PHP 5.4.11 and I have problem - downloading .zip file always stop at downloaded file size 19.8 MB (20 286 KB). If zip flie size less than 19MB then download successfully done But sometimes downloaded file has 35MB/64MB or more then download stop at 19.8 MB. 
my server Memory_limit is 128M.

I used readfile($file); to download zip.

Download file code as below :

```
$file='Daawat-E-Ishq.zip'; // zip file name with path
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();
ob_end_flush();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_end_clean();
readfile($file);    
unlink($file);
```

Comment: Consider displaying the return value of `set_time_limit(0)` for debugging purposes.  If it returns `FALSE` then it is failing to unset the script time limit, most likely due to a `php.ini` directive.  Or, it's possible that your web server is configured to kill scripts that run too long.  (Apache defaults to killing scripts that run for 5 minutes.)

Comment: set_time_limit(0) returns "1". that means it works fine. how to set Apache killing time?

Comment: It could be set by `php_admin_value` or by the apache `Timeout` directive.  You would have to change both of them if they are both set.  (`Timeout` has a default value of 300, which is 5 minutes.)

Comment: Is thr any othr way to download zip ?

Comment: Just link directly to the .zip file?